# Change Skype Button Image

Tags: php, javascript, skype

I am using https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/generator for skype call functionality.
I want to change image of skype icon when user is offline .I am using http://mystatus.skype.com/prince.txt for status.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dev.skype.com/uri/skype-uri.js"></script>
    <div id="SkypeButton_Call_prince_1">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Skype.ui({
          "name": "call",
          "element": "SkypeButton_Call_prince_1",
          "participants": ["prince"],
          "imageSize": 32
        });
      </script>
    </div>
```

but that code (and all the others) that is provided comes with it's own skype logo button. I'm trying to get the above to function with a custom image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.svenkauber.com/blog/making-custom-skype-buttons

Comment: @svenkauber I want to change in button provide by  https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/generator